# Booting error after update of Geforce 3060 driver to 515.48 in ubuntu 20

Tags: boot

I am getting loading initial ramdisk error after updating drivers for Geforce 3060 from 495.23 to 515.48 in ubuntu 20. I have to update the drivers for carla simulator and unreal engine and now I am stuck.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9dMJ.jpg)
Please help me!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to clarify the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running, as "Ubuntu 20" could mean several things (Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu 20.10, and Ubuntu Core 20). Thanks